# How to distinguish between WCF function calls with different parameters?

Tags: wcf, silverlight

I'm using a WCF to read emails (IMAP) in my Silverlight application (Visual studio 2010, C#). I've created a function which reads email, it takes a string parameter which can be inbox, outbox or draft, how can I understand in my `myFunctionCompleted` function that what has been my input parameter in `myFunctionAsync`?

For instance I call:

```
ReadMailAsync("inbox");
ReadMailAsync("outbox");
```

Should I call `ReadMailCompleted` twice (each for one `ReadMailAsync`)? How can I distinguish my `ReadMailCompleted` so that I can read correct results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the folder as the asyncState object while calling `ReadMailAsync`:

```
var folder = "inbox";
ReadMailAsync(folder, folder);
```

The asyncState object will be given back to you in the `ReadMailCompleted` handler:

```
void OnReadMailCompleted(object sender, ReadMailCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var folder = e.Result.AsyncState as string; //now you have the input parameter...
}
```

Comment: thanks, I was always wondering about this extra parameter! I think it is the key to this problem